# iOS 8 Photo Library -- Error adding an asset using PHAssetChangeRequest

Tags: ios8, photosframework

I am getting an "Operation not permitted" error when attempting to create a photo asset using `[PHAssetChangeRequest creationReqeustForAssetFromImageAtFileURL:]`.  I am trying to copy another photo from the Photo Library, by first getting the path name to the first photo.

The function works as expected when running on an emulator, but fails when I run it on an actual device.  Emulator and device all running iOS 8.3.  The iPad is set up to store Photos on iCloud, the emulator is not.

**My code snippet**

```
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
          PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest = 
                   [PHAssetChangeReques creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL:currentImagePath];
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
       if (!success) {
           NSLog(@"Error creating asset: %@", error);
       }
```

The `currentImagePath` comes from `[PHImageManager requesstImageDataForAsset:]`, giving the asset of the photo I am trying to copy.  The path looks like this when run on the actual iPad:

```
     file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101IMPRT/IMG_1258.JPG
```

It looks like this when I run it in the emulator:

```
     file:///Users/<my-name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<long UUID-type code>/data/Media/PhotoData/Mutations/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0002/Adjustments/FullSizeRender.jpg
```

Getting an error on the creation request of:

**error message**

> Unable to create data from file Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=257 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 257.)"
>   UserInfo=0x17046ac40
>   {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0042.JPG,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x1702480a0 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   Operation not permitted"}

Interestingly the creation request succeeds on all platforms if I use a UIImage* with the function `[PHAssetChangeRequest creationReqeustForAssetFromImage:]`.

I would appreciate if someone could explain what is going on.  Is it related to storing the photos on the Cloud?  I have tried turning off iCloud for photos on the iPad but I still get the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, if you are using the Cloud, you may need to use `networkAccessAllowed: Bool:` This will check to see if you can download the image from the cloud if necessary.

I am not sure exactly the context of your problem, because this post is a little unclear. Did you check the dictionary `resultHandler` for any errors in the function call

```
func requestImageForAsset(_ asset: PHAsset!,
               targetSize targetSize: CGSize,
              contentMode contentMode: PHImageContentMode,
                  options options: PHImageRequestOptions!,
            resultHandler resultHandler: ((UIImage!,
                [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) -> PHImageRequestID
```

Before editing an asset, use its `canPerformEditOperation` method to see if the asset allows editing.

"To edit an asset’s image or video content, first begin a content editing session with the asset’s `requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:completionHandler:` method. You commit a content edit by setting the `contentEditingOutput` property of a change request within a change block. For more information about asset content editing, see [PHAsset Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014383)."

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did check network access allowed. And the result handler gave no error. And did check canPerformEditOperation. I didn't show all of my code in an attempt to make the question clearer; guess that didn't work

Comment: no problem. Is there a reason why you are wanting to use the URL instead of the image with creationRequestForAssetFromImage(YourImageHere). I believe that this will save the image to the photo album, not copy it. What exactly do you mean by copy another photo from the photo library?

Comment: I was trying to set the IPTC metadata and did not want to lose the existing EXIF and IPTC metadata. As I understand it the image doesn't have the metadata.